# Angular js table with columns determined by object data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list that contains objects that have variable data:

```
Object.id = 0;
Object.map1 = [{key, value}, {key,value}, ...]
```

What I have is the unchanged data(like the ID) which I put as a column and then it's value in the row.

However, all the keys from the map need to be columns as well with the mapped value in the respective row for them, because each request to the service can return different data. So the output should be something like:

```
ID                   KEY1         KEY2          ...
ID.VALUE             VALUE1       VALUE2        ...
...
```

I'm new to angular hope this makes sense.

EDIT: What I've been trying for columns:

```
<thead>
<th ng-repeat="(column,v) in List.Objects[0].map1">
<a href="">{{column}}</a></th>
</th>
</thead>
```

Comment: Will each set have consistent keys for all objects in that set?

Comment: ok...but on each request will they be consistent like `[{name:'xx',age:23}, {name:'yy',age:73}]` so each object has same keys across set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried my best to understand what you need, and I've come up with this example, I hope it answered your question:

```js
angular.module('MyApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.List = [{
    id: 1,
    map1: [{
      key: 'key1',
      value: '789'
    }, {
      key: 'key2',
      value: '987'
    }]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    map1: [{
      key: 'key1',
      value: 'bbb'
    }, {
      key: 'key2',
      value: 'ddd'
    }]
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<table ng-app='MyApp' ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
  <tr>
    <th>
      id
    </th>
    <th ng-repeat="(column,v) in List[0].map1">
      {{v.key}}
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="map in List">
    <td>
      {{map.id}}
    </td>
    <td ng-repeat="(column,v) in map.map1">
      {{v.value}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given data something like:

```
$scope.items= [
  {
    "key-1": "Item-1-1",
    "key-2": "Item-1-2",
    "key-3": "Item-1-3",       
  },
  {
    "key-1": "Item-2-1",
    "key-2": "Item-2-2",
    "key-3": "Item-2-3"        
  }
]
```

You can create an array of the keys from the first item in array using

```
 $scope.fields= Object.keys($scope.items[0]);
```

Then use the fields array to repeat over to create the needed table columns

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="heading in fields">{{heading}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
      <td ng-repeat="key in fields">
         {{item[key]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/hXcYD1UUrf5gTCpCjXoy?p=preview)**</kbd>